# how do I store stories in MySQL table?

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

I want to store articles in MySQL data base. how do I create a table for the same??

Comment: Probably want to flesh this question out a bit more.
Are you a developer?
Do you have any knowledge of databases?
Are you storing the actual data? Or a file containing an article?

Do you have MySQL installed?  
What machine are you using?
Is this going to be on a server? Or just used internally? Or on your own machine?

Is it to be linked to a web application?

Comment: This question may be a bit too broad to get reasonable answers for this site.  Maybe you can ask the question another way, like how you should proceed past the place where you are stuck.

Comment: You might as well ask "I want to build a house, how do I use a tool?". It all depends on what you want to accomplish, and how you want to accomplish it.

Answer (score 2):

Use `CREATE TABLE`

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html

Here is an example:

```
CREATE TABLE stories (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    author VARCHAR(100),
    content BLOB,
    cur_timestamp TIMESTAMP(8)
);
```

Also you can try the `TEXT` data type:

```
CREATE TABLE stories (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    author VARCHAR(100),
    content TEXT,
    cur_timestamp TIMESTAMP(8)
);
```